# amazon ec2 cpu or hard slower than my home-linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cpu, hard-drive

I'm using small size ec2.

its noticeably slower than my less than $800 home linux machine.
(about average machine purchased 6month ago)

I don't know cpu or hard-disk is the bottleneck.
Wonder if there's a way to tell which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, if you want to monitor your EC2 instance, consider using Amazon's cloudwatch ( http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/ ). This service can monitor all your instance's resources, such as CPU utilization, memory usage, network latency, and request counts. It's also free in the amazon free tier.

If you're looking for more detailed monitoring, consider serverdensity service ( http://www.serverdensity.com/cloud-monitoring/ ). They can monitor software installed on the server itself, such as apache service